# Fontspec mathbb fonts changed even though latin modern math font is used

Tags: xetex, fontspec, latin-modern

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[FakeBold=2]
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}[FakeBold=2]

\begin{document}
    
        \begin{align*}
            v\in\mathbb{V}\\
            f\in\mathbb{F}
        \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

This code prints  [image: this] whereas

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}

\usepackage{pdfrender, xcolor}
\pdfrender{StrokeColor=black,LineWidth=.2pt,TextRenderingMode=2}
%\usepackage{fontspec}

%\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[FakeBold=2]
%\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}[FakeBold=2]

\begin{document}
    
        \begin{align*}
            v\in\mathbb{V}\\
            f\in\mathbb{F}
        \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

prints [image: this]

I am not sure why the font is changed with `fontspec`. I want to preserve the second style (the default Latin Modern) while using `fontspec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font you want is Computer Modern not Latin Modern. You can reset `mathbb`like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[FakeBold=2]

\let\mathbbalt\mathbb
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}[FakeBold=2]
\let\mathbb\mathbbalt

\begin{document}
    
        \begin{align*}
            v\in\mathbb{V}\\
            f\in\mathbb{F}
        \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. is there a way to increase the font weight of the mathbb fonts? in the second example I showed using `pdfrender`, the bb fonts have the lines a bit thicker but with fontspec all fonts get fakbolded but not these for some reason